# How does the overdrive voltage relate to the transistor size?

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit

I am a student currently learning analog IC design. I am wondering how the overdrive voltage of a transistor(Let's say NMOS/PMOS), relates to the size of the transistor.

For example, if an NMOS transistor M1 with size 1X has an overdrive voltage of Vov, what is the overdrive voltage of NMOS transistor M2 with size 0.25X in terms of Vov? Similarly, if a PMOS transistor M3 with size 1X has an overdrive voltage of Vov, what is the overdrive voltage of PMOS transistor M4 with size 4X in terms of Vov?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www-mtl.mit.edu/researchgroups/icsystems/pubs/theses/narendra_phd_2002.pdf see page 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overdrive voltage is defined from the gate-source voltage and threshold voltage as:

$$ V_{ov} = V_{gs} - V_{th} $$

If you assume \$V_{th}\$ is constant with respect to sizing (a normal first order approximation) then the answer to your question is: The overdrive voltage is **not** related to the transistor size.

**Except**, if the device you are varying is already connected in a circuit, allowing \$V_{gs}\$ to change depending on the transistor size.

If the device is connected so \$V_{gs}\$ may vary, but \$I_{ds}\$ is fixed then you can reason :

- If the width increases, \$V_{ov}\$ will go down.
- If the length increases, \$V_{ov}\$ will go up.

If \$I_{ds}\$ is fixed and the device is operating in saturation then the following *approximation* might be useful : $$V_{ov}\propto\sqrt{\frac{L}{W}}$$

If \$I_{ds}\$ is fixed and the device is operating in subthreshold then the following *approximation* might be useful : $$V_{ov}\propto\log{\frac{L}{W}}$$

These approximations don't take into account variations that occur due to changed \$V_{ds}\$ and \$V_{sb}\$, or changes in \$V_{th}\$. To get a more detailed result take your favorite MOSFET equation and extract \$V_{ov}\$ from it.